# declaring integer array in objective c without NSArray.n

Tags: objective-c

(Question updated after first comment)

`int max_size = 20;

int h[max_size];`

Debugging gives a value of [-1] for h when using max_size to initialize;

If instead I initialize using an integer. So the code is:`int h[20]` , it works fine.

This was with GCC 4.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: Works for me. It might help if you reduce it to a simple test case and update your question to include that code so we can see specifically what's going wrong.

Comment: +1 @Chuck.  Anything you can do in C you can do in Objective-C.

Comment: Where are you declaring your array? Inside a method/function? Or in the global scope? And what exactly is -1 according to the debugger?

Comment: All the code is written in the same function scope. h[0] or h[max_size] gives -1. I'm using GCC 4.2 as a compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just compiled and ran the following program incorporating your code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main() {
    int max_size = 20;
    int h[max_size];

    h[0] = 5;
    NSLog(@"It is %d", h[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

It worked fine. The problem is something besides simply declaring an array.

This was with GCC 4.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.4.

Comment: My complier is GCC 4.2 on Mac OS X 10.6. And if I change it to LLVM GCC 4.2, then it works fine, but I don't see the variable in my debugger window. I don't even know what LLVM is. There must be an alternate solution.

Comment: In this case the compiler knows that max_size can not be changed between the first two lines of your function thus it can decide the size if the `h` array at compile time. Your code will not work if the value of max_size is calculated in a more complicated way.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, some compilers need to know the size of stack-allocated arrays explicitly at compile-time.  This (possibly) being the case, you could make your max_size variable const or an #define macro (or an integer literal, as you've done.)  Alternatively, you could dynamically allocate the array and then the size could be any-old variable

ex:

```
int *array = calloc(max_size, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: This is not the case for GCC, and when it is the case, a compiler that doesn't support that feature will normally flag the declaration as an error rather than silently compiling nonsense.

Comment: Ah, that shows some ignorance on my part.  Thanks for the correction.